# C++ returning a vector (conversion of int to non-scalar type)

Tags: c++, vector, types, int, scalar

I am trying to fill a vector with integers starting with -1 and going until the negative of my size parameter. For example: if the parameter is 6, then I want the vector to have 6 items, from -1 to -6. Oh and if the size parameter is less than 1 I want to return an empty parameter.

I am getting a "conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type" error message. To the best of my knowledge this is good code but obviously I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int negativity(int size) {
    std::vector<int> vect;
    if (size < 1) {
        return vect;
    }
    for (int i=-1; i > size; i--) {
        vect.push_back(i);
    }
    return vect;
}
```

Comment: @dmg or not loop at all

Comment: No, that's not the error message you're getting from that code.

Comment: @molbdnilo On the other hand, his second loop is likely to run for quite a while.

Answer (score 5):

The return type of your function is `int`, but you are returning `std::vector<int>`.

This should correct compiler error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> negativity(int size) {
    std::vector<int> vect;
    if (size < 1) {
        return vect;
    }
    for (int i=-1; i > size; i--) {
        vect.push_back(i);
    }
    return vect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/** other implementation;
 - Usage of an argument to avoid duplication of copying object.
 */
size_t negativity(std::vector<int>& vResult, const unsigned int uiHowmany)
{
    vResult.clear();
    for(unsigned int i=1; i < uiHowmany; ++i)
    {
        vResult.push_back((-1)*i);
    }
    return vResult.size();
}
```